# Compound subsetting by factor levels in R?

Tags: r

I haven't been able to get compound statements to work when attempting to subset data by factor levels. Here's a synthetic example I concocted using the Houston airport dataset:

```
library(hflights)

# Add a factor column for testing. 
hflights$ccfac <- as.factor(hflights$CancellationCode)
levels(hflights$ccfac)

# Filtering on a single factor level works fine. 
filtered_df <- hflights[hflights$ccfac != "C", ]

# Compound filtering on multiple non-factor items works fine. 
filtered_df <- hflights[hflights$Month == 2 | hflights$Month == 7, ]

# Compound filtering on multiple factor levels doesn't work.
# filtered_df is identical to test_df.
filtered_df <- hflights[hflights$ccfac != "A" | hflights$ccfac != "B", ]
```

Google and StackOverflow searches haven't turned up anything. Is there something obvious missing in my syntax, or is there another way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use

```
filtered_df <- hflights[hflights$ccfac != "A" & hflights$ccfac != "B", ]
```

Otherwise, since the two conditions are logically disjoint, you will just get all `TRUE`s. (If `ccfac` is neither `A` nor `B`, it will be true. If it is `A` the latter is true, and if it is `B`, the former is true. Hence, it is a tautology.)

Comment: or `subset(hflights,!ccfac %in% c("A","B"))`

Comment: hadley doesn't like `subset` because it uses non-standard evaluation.

Comment: I know, but it's handy for top-level (interactive/scripting) use.  The `!ccfac %in% c("A","B")` part is handy whether or not you like `subset()`.

Comment: So, something obvious missing, just not in my syntax. Gah. Thank you! :)